# PHP OOP How to process data returned by DB query

Tags: php, oop

Im trying to imprive my skills and move away from procedural style coding, however the switch is not coming easy and I am very much new to the OOP concept so please keep this in mind when reading / answering.

I have the following method inside a class called `Jobs{}`

The task of the method is pretty simple query the database for all the different job categories in a table and return it.

The following is an extract from the code inside my class

```
   function dispCategories(){
     $sql = "SELECT DISTINCT category FROM jobs";
     $stmnt = $db->prepare($sql);
     $stmnt->execute();
     return $stmnt->fetchAll();
 }
```

Now inside my view or html page I do the following

```
$obj = new Jobs();
$categories = $obj->dispCategories()
?>
    <!--DISPLAY CATEGORIES -->
    <form id="getJobByCategory" method="post" action="">
        <select name="selectedCategory">
            <?php
            foreach ($categories as $category){
                ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $category['category'] ?>">
                    <?php echo $category['category'] ?>
                </option>
            <?php
            }
            ?>
```

**My Question**

When you look at my code where I initiate the object `Jobs{}` and call the method categories `$categories = $obj->dispCategories()`

I use a `foreach` loop combined with some html & php. Is this an acceptable way of doing things in the OOP realm?

- Should I rather create a seperate method like `getCategories()` where I loop over the results returned by the `dispCategories()` method?
- Alternatively should I just process the data returned by the `dispCategories()` method inside the actual `dispCategories()` method...

Hope this make sense. Just looking for some best practices and guidance here, however please keep in mind im a rookie.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Should I rather create a seperate method like getCategories() where I loop over the results returned by the dispCategories() method?*

You're definitely on the right track with what you have now.  Since your `dispCategories()` method only returns one column, it makes sense that it would return a one-dimensional array, a simple list of the values rather than a 2D structure that retains characteristics of the SQL query that generated it.  I would probably modify the method to fetch all rows and then reduce them to a single array, which you then return. This makes it unnecessary to create another method just for looping over the categories returned by `dispCategories()`.

Assuming PHP 5.5+, you can easily do this with [`array_column()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php):

```
function dispCategories(){
     $sql = "SELECT DISTINCT category FROM jobs";
     $stmnt = $db->prepare($sql);
     $stmnt->execute();
     // Return a simple 1D array of the category only
     return array_column('category', $stmnt->fetchAll());
 }
```

It's then a simple `foreach` to list them out without needing to access array keys.

```
 foreach ($categories as $category){
 ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $category; ?>">
            <?php echo $category; ?>
        </option>
 <?php
 }
```

Remember that you may need to call `htmlspecialchars()` on the `$category` value if it may contain characters requiring HTML entity encoding.

*Alternatively should I just process the data returned by the dispCategories() method inside the actual dispCategories() method...*

No, I don't think you ought to do this.  As you learn OOP, read up on the concept of *separation of concerns* and on the MVC (model-view-controller) pattern.  If you were to create a method in your `Jobs` class that created this HTML block, it would then be performing work that is more appropriately done by your view code. It should be the responsibility of the `Jobs` class to retrieve items from the database, provide information about them, and prepare them to be passed to a view or template, but the view or template HTML should retain responsibility for organizing a list of categories from the `Jobs` class into markup appropriate for however you happen to be displaying it.

Comment: Thank YOU so much for this detailed answer, it is really appreciated.

Comment: @TimothyCoetzee You're welcome, best of luck with your learning.